# Why does this statement always return false?

Tags: php, if-statement, boolean

I need to find out why it says "Old Version" every time even when `$a = true`. If `$a` is true, it should do the if block and none of the others.

```
<?php
$launcherv = "13";
$gamev = "1326382442000";
$sessid = math.rand(1, 1000000000000000);
$ticket = math.rand(1, 1000000000000);
$user =      "";
$password =  "";
$version =   "";
$a = false;
$b = false;
$c = false;


if ($version == $launcherv){
$a = true;

} else {
$a = false;

}
if ($user == ""){
$b = false;

} else {


$b = 'true';

}
if ($password == ""){
$c = false;

} else {
$c = true;

}




if ($a && $b && $c){
echo ($gamev.":".$ticket.":".$user.":".$sessid);
}
elseif(!$a){
echo "Old Version";
}
elseif(!$b){
echo "Bad Login";
}
elseif(!$c){
echo "Bad Login";
}

?>
```

Comment: oh come on, do some debugging...

Comment: I would say that you should change your title to soemthing more descriptive, but what could describe this?

Comment: the output code you need to scroll for lol i will try elseif instead of if, and i dont understand how i would debug this. tell it to echo after every line of code? lol

Comment: You code would be a lot more readable and compact if you just wrote stuff like `$a = ($version == $launcherv);`

Comment: @user1116644: YES, something like that... (but maybe, just maybe, some lines are more important)

Comment: also, i just dont see how i could debug this type of script.

Comment: of you want to test it here it is, just change the params if you want

Comment: http://rerepo.tk/mcv.php?user=test&password=test&version=13

Comment: @user1116644: this type? are you suggesting you don't have problems with the other ones? doubt it... `var_dump($a);`

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($version == $launcherv){
    $a = true;
} else {
    $a = false;
}
```

Ok, so `$version =   "";`, and `$launcherv = "13";`, so `$a = false`.

```
if ($a && $b && $c){
    echo ($gamev.":".$ticket.":".$user.":".$sessid);
}
elseif(!$a){
    echo "Old Version";
}
```

Because `$a = false`, it goes to the `elseif`, which evaluates to true (`!false == true`), and `echo "Old Version";` is run.

Comment: i pass paramater s in the url to make it 13

Comment: Are you doing `$version = $_GET['version'];` anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

You have set `$a` to `false` which returns the bool `false`.

When you check if $a doesn't equal true, it always doesn't return true, because `$a` never gets set to `true`. This is because `$version = "";` and `$launcherv  = "13";` so that will not be true and it will skip to the else which sets `$a` to false again.

In the other question when you were told that you could do this, they told you that you could set `$a` to `$version >= $launcherv` which if evaluated would return true or false depending on whether the statement was true or false. Right after that though, they said...

> The short variables are likely to confuse future readers. Therefore, you should write:
>
> ```
> if ($version >= $launcherv) {
> ```

Comment: i changed it to that before i posted it, just an older version

Answer (score 0):

So, judging from the link you posted in the comments above:

```
rerepo.tk/mcv.php?user=test&password=test&version=13
```

I see that you're trying to pass in variables through the URL using register_globals

The problem here is that while you pass in the variables initially from the url, you redefine the values of those variables in your script to "" in your code.  So initially, it was for example

```
$version = 13
```

from the assignment in your URL, but after you called

```
$version = ""
```

this overwrote what you assigned $version in the URL, since it was run afterwards.

Because of this, your value of version is always "", causing your script to constantly get the value of $a to be false, which has been explained in detail by Josh.

So basically, to fix this problem, all you have to do is remove this part of your code:

```
$user =      "";
$password =  "";
$version =   "";
```

I tested this on my own computer, and it worked.  However, in the case that this doesn't solve your problem, it is likely "register_globals" is turned off on your server.

Edit: If you are now using $_POST to pass the variables, then assign your variables as follows:

```
$user =      $_POST["user"];
$password =  $_POST["password"];
$version =   $_POST["version"];
```

This is assuming that the variables you're posting is named the same way as when you had it passed in the URL.

Comment: are you still having problems with it? if you are, could you update the code to reflect that?